# Looking for another partition of 100

Tags: calculation-puzzle, no-computers, number-theory, graph-theory

The sum of ten, not necessarily different, positive integers is 100. If placed adequately on the vertices of this graph, two of them will be joined by a line if, and only if, they have a common divisor greater than 1 (i.e. they are not relatively prime).
[image]

What are those ten integers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by labeling as follows:

[image]

Solution process:

> The only pairs of integers that could possibly be equal are $U$ and $X$, and $W$ and $Z$.  This is because if two integers are equal to each other then they're certainly relatively prime to the same integers.  Thus, for example, $Q \ne R$ because $R$ and $Y$ are not relatively prime but $Q$ and $Y$ are.
>
>  Unfortunately we can't automatically deduce that $U = X$ or $W = Z$.  It may be possible that, without loss of generality, $U = X^k$ for some integer $k$, with a similar possible relationship between $W$ and $Z$.
>
>  Because $U$ and $X$ are only joined to each other, I suspect that each has only one prime factor (that is, each is some power of the same prime).  Theoretically it's possible that, say, $U = pq$ for two distinct primes $p$ and $q$, but then no other vertex aside from $X$ can have $p$ or $q$ as a factor, and that seems very limiting since we're trying to sum to $100$.
>
>  I started by building systematically and had to adjust as I went along.  My graph theory and number theory skills are rusty so if there's a more systematic way that doesn't involve guess-and-check, I don't know what it is.
>
>  First, $S,T,Y$ are all adjacent to each other (adjacent = "joined by an edge" in graph theory terms [edge = "line segment" in graph theory terms]), so $S,T,Y$ must have at least one prime factor in common.  This common factor is $3$.
>
>  Since $S$ is adjacent to $V$, and $T$ and $Y$ are not, then $S$ must have a prime factor that $T$ and $Y$ do not.  This factor is $7$.
>
>  Also, $Y$ is adjacent to $R$, while $S$ and $T$ are not.  Thus $Y$ must have a prime factor that $S$ and $T$ do not.  This factor is $2$.
>
>  $R$ must have another prime factor that no other vertex has yet, since $R$ is adjacent to $Q$ and no other vertex is adjacent to $Q$.  This factor is $5$.
>
>  If we assume the simplest case, i.e., no powers of primes and just the primes themselves, then we have $Q = 5, R = 10, S = 21, T = 3, V = 7, Y = 6.$
>
>  Thus the total sum so far is $5+10+21+3+7+6 = 52$.  This means we need $U+X+W+Z = 48$.  What luck! $48 = 22 + 26 = 11 + 11 + 13 + 13$.  Take $U = X = 13$ and $W = Z = 11$ and we get one possible answer:
>
>  [image]

Comment: The answer is unique.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos, up to isomorphism.  :P  $\quad$

Comment: The partition of 100 is unique. No other partition of 100 has the same graph.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos, I know, I was thinking isomorphism because the $11$s and $13$s could be swapped, thereby having different labels.  But I forgot that (a) I provided the labels and (b) they're irrelevant anyway since a graph is just vertices and edges.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, there should be many solutions to this. Then again, English is not my native language.
Clockwise, starting from the topmost left: 26, 16, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 2, 8, 2.

I assume that I am wrong since this seems very easy, so please do correct me and explain if I haven't understood.

Comment: I think that's not right because $26$ and $8$ aren't joined by an edge, which, according to the rules, means they shouldn't have any common factors greater than $1$.  But they do ($2$).

Comment: Ah! Correct, they should be joined. This is what I have overlooked, that lines should not be static! I was approaching the graph in an incorrect way. Thank you! Please downvote and flag this answer. :)

Comment: You can always delete your own answer if you want...

Comment: Meh, I largely find downvoting to be petty and almost never do it.  Also, what Mithrandir said.

Comment: But I'll flag so I can get progress towards a badge I'll never earn.  :P  $\quad$